# How to execute JUnit 5 @Tag tests with Ant?

Tags: junit, ant, junit5, ant-junit

How do I use Ant to run a JUnit 5 test annotated with `@Tag`?

For instance:

```java
class Tax {
    @Test
    @Tag("taxes")
    void testingTax() {
    }
}
```

In Maven, I can do the following to either include or exclude. However I don't know how to make it work in Ant.

```xml
<properties>
    <includeTags>taxes</includeTags>
    <excludeTags>Promo</excludeTags>
</properties>
```

Kindly advise.

Comment: How are you launching JUnit 5 tests from Ant?

The only way I know of is to call ConsoleLauncher from ant.

If this is the case, you can pass -t parameter with the names of the tags you want executed.

link to the ConsoleLauncher: http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher

Comment: I launch JUnit test from Elipse not by ConsoleLaucher. However thanks for telling me that it can use -t parameter with the names of the tags. @kotse Thanks!

Comment: Aha, Eclipse. So you are using built-in JUnit5 IDE support. 

I have no idea if you can run different tags from Eclipse :) Maybe you can pass tag names as a parameter to your run configuration, but did Eclipse implement and supports it - I haven't tried, as I am an IDEA user.

Comment: If you're only running your tests in Eclipse, why are you asking about how to run them in Ant?

Comment: Hi Sam, I was just answering Kotse saying I usually run from Eclipse by not mentioning ant but ConsoleLauncher. Yes, I still having problem running the annotation @Tag in Ant. Any clue?

Comment: @kotse, not sure if Eclipse implement and support it. Need to find out. However I was wishing it could be run in ant for CI purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apache Ant developers JUnit5 is currently not supported. However, according to this [bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61796), they have started working. There is also a message about this topic [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@ant.apache.org/msg46315.html).

Comment: The support is minimal - does not support forking for example

Answer (score 2):

Since 10.7 its now supported.

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitlauncher.html

(includeTags and excludeTags)

I needed that also, so I contributed that.